# how to retrieve data from Bigcommerce using Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, integration, bigcommerce

I am trying to connect a Rails application with the Bigcommerce API but I can't and I don't know why.

I made the next:

1. Add 'gem bigcommerce' to my gem file
2. Execute 'bundle install'
3. Put the code behind in the ApplicationController index

   ```
   def index
   api = Bigcommerce::Api.new({
                                  :store_url => "http://mystore.mybigcommerce.com",
                                  :username  => "user",
                                  :api_key   => "3a0ce...[my api key]"
                              })
   puts api.time
   ```

   end
4. Stop and Start Rails server
5. I received an error saying 'undefined method `time' for #'

[image]

Does any body could tell me what I am doing wrong and **how to configure Bigcommerce  in a Rails app?** I found the official [documentation](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby), but it's not very clear for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you added require at the beggining of your ApplicationController file?

```
 require 'bigcommerce'
```

Comment: Yes, I added that line to my ApplicationController file, but the error persists

Comment: Please print api.methods too ;)